# Gyroscope absolute value

Tags: android, sensors, gyroscope

I have the following code for using the Gyroscope sensor, but it doesn't fit my needs, because it only gives me the xyz changes in a specific time. Is there a way to get the absolute xyz-rotation coordinates. Like if my smartphone is laying on the ground it has x = 0° and when it is tilted it has something like e.g. 34°

```
SensorManager sensorManager =
                (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        Sensor gyroscopeSensor =
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);


SensorEventListener gyroscopeSensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
                float dx = sensorEvent.values[0];
                float dy = sensorEvent.values[1];
                float dz = sensorEvent.values[2];
                Log.e("COORD",dx + " " + dy + " " + dz);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
        }
    };

    sensorManager.registerListener(gyroscopeSensorListener,
            gyroscopeSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```